# Active nav bar doesn't change the first time

Tags: javascript, css, toggle, nav

I am trying to change navigation a tag color when the user clicks on the `<a>` tag. The JS is working fine, except the first time the user clicks on the `<a>` tag; only in the second time the a tag color changes.

**JavaScript:**

```
   function toggleNav(pageId){
     activeColor();
     var href = 'html/' + pageId + '.html';
     window.onload = document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = 
   loadPage(href);

  }

  function activeColor(){
var header = document.getElementById("allNav");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("notActive");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
      var button1 = btns[i]; 
        button1.addEventListener("click" , 
            function() {
                var current = document.getElementsByClassName(" active");
                console.log(current.length);
                for (var i = 0; i <  current.length + 1; i++) { 
                  current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" 
        active", "");
                }

                var myString = this.id;
                var stringLength = myString.length; 
                var lastChar = myString.charAt(stringLength - 1);

                if(lastChar == "2"){
                    var add = document.getElementById(this.id);
                    var id2Nmae = add.id.slice(0, -1);
                    var add2 = document.getElementById(id2Nmae);
                    add.className += " active";
                    add2.className += " active";
                }
                else{
                    var add = document.getElementById(this.id);
                    var id2Nmae = add.id + "2";
                    var add2 = document.getElementById(id2Nmae);
                    add.className += " active";
                    add2.className += " active";
                }

              });
            }
      }
```

**HTML :**

```
        <div id="allNav">
    <div class="sidebar" id="mySidebar" style="display:block">
          <button id="open" onclick="Toggle()">
            <a ><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
          </button>
          <a href="#" onclick="toggleNav('goals')" class="notActive active" id="nav12"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot"></i></a>
          <a href="#"onclick="toggleNav('Restrictions')" class="notActive" id="nav32"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i></a>
          <a href="#" onclick="toggleNav('Workout')" class="notActive" id="nav42"><i class="fas fa-burn"></i></a>
          <a href="#" onclick="toggleNav('Food')" class="notActive" id="nav52"><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i></a>
          <a href="#" onclick="toggleNav('Progress')" class="notActive" id="nav62"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i></a>
          <a href="#" onclick="toggleNav('Message')" class="notActive" id="nav72"><i class="far fa-comments"></i></a>
          <a href="#" onclick="toggleNav('Notification')" class="notActive" id="nav82"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Post the whole code

Comment: "when the user click on the", "except the first time the user click on the," -> on the.. what?

Comment: I edited the question... I hope now it's more understandable

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded to solve the problem, It was an issue I made by the DOM path not correct.
In the first time the page loads, the default load was the "goals" id by the next JS code:

```
var href = 'html/goals.html';
 window.onload = document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = loadPage(href);
```

In this why the "addEventListener" needed to load at the first time and only in the second time the function can run.

I changed the default function to:

```
   toggleNav('goals')
```

I hope I helped if somebody will experience the same issue.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your script and in the console I got

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
```

(in chrome dev tools) Have you checked the element view (next to console) to see how the javascript is interacting with the HTML?

from looking at the code, the number "2" is for ids that are selected, however, everything ends with the number 2 and it is never actually removed. Is that intentional?

The loop doesn't seem to like "this.id" as it loses the reference (error above).

have you put in alerts to see where the pointer is in the loop?

Comment: Hi Captain Comedy, Can you explain what is "the element view"? In addition,  the id numbers for example id="nav42" it's because I have another nav with ids from 1 -7 (for some reason I couldn't past it to the question) - Do you think it can impact the result? I put console.log() to check the loop it works fine except the first time.

Comment: I see, then we would need to see the whole script as your js is interacting with code we can't see, I recommend jsfiddle.

Comment: I shared with jsfiddle the all code, this is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/v4muwtp8, I didn't know it before, nice to know this tool thank you.

Comment: yep, pretty handy.
When looking at your fiddle, the icons don't show, it's because you haven't included the cdn to your third party javascript / css files.

on the left side of the window is a link called "resources" an input field to paste the link. if you want to add for example bootstrap, just type "bootstrap" in the field and a dropdown will appear - choose the desired cdn and it will add it .